# Force Close!! Button to assign random color in RGB Values 0-255

Tags: java, android, button, random, integer

everything else in my app works, but when I add

```
public void onClickRandomColor(View v) {
        Random rRed = null;
        Random rGreen = null;
        Random rBlue = null;
        int min = 0, max = 255;
        int randomRed = rRed.nextInt(max - min + 1) + min;
        int randomGreen = rGreen.nextInt(max - min + 1) + min;
        int randomBlue = rBlue.nextInt(max - min + 1) + min;
        Rset = randomRed;
        Gset = randomGreen;
        Bset = randomBlue;
    }
```

to MainActivity.java and the ONCLICK line to activity_main.xml

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/btnRandom"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btnChoose"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:onClick="onClickRandomColor"
        android:text="@string/random"/>
```

She force closes on me. There are plenty of other controls, the sliders use the Rset, Gset, and Bset just fine. It has to be something with my method of obtaining random integers.

Comment: Once you have a non-null `Random`, you should consider condensing the code. Something like `Rset = rnd.nextInt(256);` is sufficient, and removes a bunch of cruft (at least visually; excellent chance the VM ignores your unnecessary temporaries anyway.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You need to create the Random objects with `new Random()` instead of assigning null. You can't call anything on null, you have to create the object.
2. There is no point in having three different Random objects, you can get an infinite number of random numbers from a single object

Your corrected code would look like this:

```
public void onClickRandomColor(View v) {
    Random rnd = new Random();
    int min = 0, max = 255;
    int randomRed = rnd.nextInt(max - min + 1) + min;
    int randomGreen = rnd.nextInt(max - min + 1) + min;
    int randomBlue = rnd.nextInt(max - min + 1) + min;
    Rset = randomRed;
    Gset = randomGreen;
    Bset = randomBlue;
}
```

Comment: The first code fixed my problem, but this is neater. Which do I select from two right answers? How do I choose?

Answer (score 1):

You are creating Random that are initialized as nulls.

Change them to `Random rRed = new Random();`

you are basically trying to do  null.nextInt() which is obviously not gonna work.

Hopefully this helps!

Cheers!

Comment: Ok, that fixed force close, why doesn't it update the sliders? I don't ask the pop up ColorDialog to update the sliders, it just does?

Comment: Random color does cause the color shown in the center of the color picker to change howerver?

Comment: Without more code I cannot tell how you are using RSet, GSet, or BSet. But it is likely that you need to add in a function that updates your slider to the end of this onclick.

Comment: You could do this many ways: create a function that has the input parameters of RSet, GSet, and Bset and then change the slider directly, send broadcast with a Broadcastreceiver; have a timer that checks periodically for changes, etc...